# Adding gitbash to windows cmd to run make files

Tags: windows, bash, git

i have a windows machine that i installed `git` on it . on install i checked the `add the gitbash to environment` but after install when i run a smiple command like `ls` in my windows cmd i get the error

```
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

now this is my env variables on my windows

[image]

the second one was added by git automatically on install but I add the first one by searching on stack overflow but none of them seems to work .

**Extra Details** :

in case you want to know what trouble it cause me . i am running some `make` commands that works properly on my `gitbash` but on my goland terminal it gives this error

```
./scripts/fmt.sh provider
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, sh C:\Users\farsh\go\src\gojeh\scripts\fmt.sh provider, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:16: run] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### TL;DR

Git for Windows deliberately only puts the bare minimum on your Windows PATH

##### Details

If you look at the `git\bin` directory, you'll see that only `git`, `bash` and `sh` are there. Then there's a `git\usr\bin` directory will the standard *nix-style utilities you're expecting, including `ls`, although not including `make` on my machine. Those are not added to your Windows path, because many of them would conflict with the standard Windows utilities, and shadowing them could have unpredictable effects on other stuff running in Windows.

So you'll find the extra stuff is only visible when you're running inside Git Bash itself, where they're expected to work the *nix way.

If you need `make` for your system, you should probably install a version intended to be used on Windows.